# Jest + Nestjs + Nestjsx Crud | Cannot set property findOne of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, crud, nestjs

I am using Nestjs with the Nestjsx-Crud library. The services classes extends the TypeOrmCrudService. I need someone services that extends TypeOrmCrudService examples. Anyone has any link or know how to fix this error below?

Currently it is my code:

```js
//jobService.spec

beforeAll(async () => {
    jobsModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        JobsService,
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(Job), useClass: JobsMockRepository },
        // dependencies

        JobTypesService,
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(JobType), useClass: JobTypesMockRepository },
      ],
    }).compile();

    jobsService = jobsModule.get<JobsService>(JobsService);
    jobsRepositoryMock = jobsModule.get(getRepositoryToken(Job));
    jobTypesService = jobsModule.get<JobTypesService>(JobTypesService);
  });

  describe('acceptJob', () => {
    it(`should return ${notFoundMessage('JobType')}`, async () => {
      const job = Mocks.getJob();
      jest.spyOn(jobTypesService, 'findOne').mockImplementation(() => undefined);
      expect(
        await jobsService.acceptJob(job.id, { serviceProviderId: faker.random.uuid() }),
      ).toThrow(notFoundMessage('JobType'));
    });
```

```js
// mockRepository

export class MockRepository<T> {
  public createQueryBuilder = jest.fn(() => this.queryBuilder);
  public manager = { transaction: (a) => Promise.resolve(a()) };
  public metadata = { connection: { options: { type: null } }, columns: [], relations: [] };
  public save = jest.fn();
  public delete = jest.fn();
  public update = jest.fn();
  public findOne = jest.fn();
  public findOneOrFail = jest.fn();
  public find = jest.fn();
  public getMany = jest.fn();
  public queryBuilder = {
    offset: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    take: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    orderBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    skip: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    limit: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    from: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    addFrom: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    andWhere: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    innerJoinAndSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    leftJoinAndSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getManyAndCount: jest.fn(),
    getMany: jest.fn(),
    getOne: jest.fn(),
    delete: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    execute: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  };
}

export class JobsMockRepository extends MockRepository<Job> {}
export class JobTypesMockRepository extends MockRepository<JobType> {}
```

```sh
-----------------
 TypeError: Cannot set property findOne of [object Object] which has only a getter
| 
|       77 |     it(`should return ${notFoundMessage('JobType')}`, async () => {
|       78 |       const job = Mocks.getJob();
|     > 79 |       jest.spyOn(jobTypesService, 'findOne').mockImplementation(() => undefined);
|          |            ^
|       80 |       expect(
|       81 |         await jobsService.acceptJob(job.id, { serviceProviderId: faker.random.uuid() }),
|       82 |       ).toThrow(notFoundMessage('JobType'));
| 
|       at ModuleMockerClass.spyOn (../node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:800:26)
|       at Object.<anonymous> (modules/jobs/jobs.service.spec.ts:79:9)
```

Can anybody help me?

---

SOLUTION:

Instead to mock service methods that extends TypeOrmCrud, mock the repository class method:

```
jest.spyOn(jobTypesRepositoryMock, 'findOne').mockResolvedValue(
                () => undefined);
```

Thanks @michalk93

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `findOne` method is a `readonly` property in TypeScript definition it can not be reassigned using `jest.spyOn` or even `Object.assign`. If you want to mock the `findOne` method you can look into the TypeScript definition of `TypeOrmCrudService` and you will see that line

```
readonly findOne: Repository<T>['findOne'];
```

It means that you can mock not the Service `findOne` method but the repository `findOne` method to achieve the same result.

So the solution is already in your mock of the repository. You can set the definition of `findOne` method like below, to return `undefined` from `findOne` like you have right now in your test:

```
public findOne = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(undefined);
```